# How to add body in axios.get in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAbDR.jpg)

I have added image for reference with api endpoint and i want to do same from frontend with react and axios but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should not be sending body in `get` requests, what is the need for that? Use `post` instead, for example.

Comment: use `post` instead of `get`. Ex: `axios.post('/yourApiPath', yourBodyObj, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})`. This shoulb be **asynhcronous** operation